# Is there an equivalent command line tool in Oracle like the SQL Server sqlcmd.exe?

Tags: oracle10g

Is there an equivalent command line tool in Oracle like the SQL Server sqlcmd.exe?

Comment: Yes, there is one :) But Oracle is not as friendly in some areas.

Comment: What it is ...I am new to oracle.. please help

Answer (score 1):

Try [SQL*Plus](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch1.htm#SQPUG008)

And here is a very [quick and simple overview](http://www.herongyang.com/jdbc/Oracle-sqlplus-Command-Line-Interface.html). You can follow these instructions to very quickly find out whether this will meet your needs.

From that same Oracle page:

> The SQL*Plus command-line interface is
>   standard on all operating systems.